# Why do we need to use "as" in python to import

Tags: python, python-import

from python docs:

```
 import_stmt:    "import" module ["as" name] ("," module ["as" name] )* 
          | "from" module "import" identifier ["as" name]
            ("," identifier ["as" name] )*
          | "from" module "import" "*" 
 module:         (identifier ".")* identifier
```

Why would we need to define an alias for a library?

Comment: What if you don't like the name it gives you?

Comment: What if you had two (or more) conflicting modules? What if you just want to save yourself some typing?

Comment: You don't *need* to. It's an option.

Comment: All three above comments constitute a complete answer to this question, in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's pretty darn common in most languages that have an import system to allow aliasing…!?

Comment: @deceze Are there any (commonly used) languages that don't?

Comment: @jhpratt I'm not claiming to know all (commonly) used languages, so I'm couching my comment in less than absolute terms… Otherwise along comes something like brainfuck++ and proves me wrong. ;)

Comment: Oh, of course no one knows all common languages, it was more of an inquiry. I can't think of any, as even JavaScript has proper module support (with aliasing!).

Comment: @jhpratt How do you do aliasing in C?

Comment: @BlownhitherMa C has header files, which is arguably not a proper module system (with imports and similar).

Answer (score 5):

There are a few occasions.

To avoid name collision

```
from bisect import bisect
from homework import bisect as my_bisect
# TODO: test if the two functions works similarly
```

To avoid long names

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

To make memes

```
import keras as tf
```

Comment: `import jackie_chan from drawings as what_is_this_I_cant_even  # made a meme`